# Haskell - how to check if an element is in a list using Foldr?

Tags: haskell

I want to check whether a element is in a list, and I want to implement it using Foldr. I know it is wrong, but I can't get any further than the code below

```
func :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
func a b = foldr (==) a b
```

I furthermore got the first line of code from the lectures, but I don't really understand why `Eq a` is necessary and what it does.

Comment: Your definition, when applied to a list like `[a, b, c, d]` and a desired element `x`, is equivalent to `a == (b == (c == (d == x)))` or `(==) a ((==) b ((==) c ((==) d x)))`. So this would require both `x` and the elements of the list to be of type `Bool`, since they’re all compared with the result of `==`. What you want instead is to write some function `step :: a -> Bool -> Bool` and choose some value `end :: Bool`, such that `step a (step b (step c (step d end)))` returns true if `a == x`, or `b == x`, and so on, and finally false otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if an element `a` is in a list you need to compare it to each element in the list. Thus whatever type `a` is, it needs to implement `Eq`.

With `:t foldr` in e.g. ghci, you can see the type signature your inner function which I will call `f` needs:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

If you use  `(==)` for `f` it does not work because you can only compare a list element to a `Bool` which should ultimately indicate whether `a` is in the list.
So you need to figure out how to get `a`, the element you want to test for into f.